# Can't boot after switching to intel driver

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

## After Switching to intel driver, Can't boot:

Result >>>[Failed] Failed to start dGPU off during boot.
See 'systemctl status Nvidia-prime-boot.service' for details.

And I was tried to switch again to Nvidia driver(As shown command) but I can't do it again.

```
$ /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia
```

Result >>>Read-only file system:

***Help me***

Answer (score 0):

You may try to switch the cards by adding **sudo** before your command.

`$ sudo /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia`

Or you can boot as root in recovery mode and type the same command again.

Answer (score 0):

Following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438908/mint-18-3-does-not-boot-after-i-changed-graphics-card-from-nvidia-to-intel

From the shell in recovery mode, i did this:
`mount -o rw,remount /`

Then ran the command you specified. Rebooted and that fixed the issue for me